# Possibility to bypass final modifier

Tags: java, android

[I've seen](https://www.androidos.net.cn/android/10.0.0_r6/raw/frameworks/base/services/core/java/com/android/server/display/AutomaticBrightnessController.java) that there exists a variable on Android which should define the minimum level of brightness:

```
private final int mScreenBrightnessRangeMinimum
```

Unfortunately it is final, so it isn't modifiable. However, I'd really like to change the minimum level of screen' brightness because the adaptive regulator on Android doesn't fit my needs in some environment conditions, in particular those cases of external weak or null lighting.
I ask if there's a way to bypass such inconvenience, that is, for example, to force another value for the above mentioned variable.

Comment: As for the Java itselt - it can be overriden using reflection - but the question is, even if you change that value, will that have any effect. My guess is that it will not.

Comment: The even trickier part is that that code almost certainly runs in some Android-internal process and you won't be able to access it from an app. You'll probably need at least root-level access (or, almost equivalently, privileged app access) to be able to interact with that in a meaningful way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the value of a final field through reflection. For example, given an instance of the class

```
class MyFinalField {
    private final int mScreenBrightnessRangeMinimum = Integer.valueOf(1000);
}

MyFinalField ff = new MyFinalField();
System.out.println(ff.mScreenBrightnessRangeMinimum); // 1000
```

you can use the `Class.getDeclaredField` method to obtain a Field object, which you can use to change the value of the field, for example:

```
private static void changeValue(MyFinalField ff, int newValue) throws IllegalAccessException {
    try {
        Field field = MyFinalField.class.getDeclaredField("mScreenBrightnessRangeMinimum");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        field.setInt(ff, newValue);
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Demo:

```
MyFinalField ff = new MyFinalField();
System.out.println(ff.mScreenBrightnessRangeMinimum);
// prints 1000
changeValue(ff, 1);
System.out.println(ff.mScreenBrightnessRangeMinimum);
// prints 1
```

Comment: Very good and accurate answer. The only doubt arises from the @JoachinSauer and Antonios comments. I hope this works: If the value effectively change, the system behaviour should follow it consequently

Comment: I also doubt if you'll be able to set a brightness below the minimum like this, but there's only one way to find out